# How to make a rectangle object visible?

Tags: java, methods, visible, bluej

This is the first part of an assignment I am currently doing, I think I've followed all the instructions correclty but there is obviously something wrong with my code. Everytime I call the draw method nothing appears, I am struggling to make the `Rectangle visible`. I have pasted the first part of the assignment below as well as my code. I would be grateful if someone could help me fix this.

Drawing a single brick

These are the steps to draw a brick:

Construct a `new Rectangle` object.
Set the position of your rectangle according to the coordinates that were passed in as parameters.
Change the size of the rectangle to be the proper size of a brick. There are two fields defined for you, one is called `bWidth` and the other is called `bHeight` and these are initialised wth values already as the width and height of a brick.
Note: Do not change the values of `bWidth or bHeight` in this task. Leave them as they are. `(bWidth = 54) (bHeight = 16)`

Add the rectangle to the `ArrayList` called bricks using the add method.
Last of all, make the rectangle visible

This is my current code:

```
private void drawBrick(int startX, int startY){

    Rectangle singleBrick = new Rectangle();

    singleBrick.setPosition(startX, startY);

    singleBrick.changeSize(54, 16);
    bricks = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    bricks.add(singleBrick);

    singleBrick.isVisible();

}
```

Comment: `isVisible()` only checks if the object is visible. I think you want `setVisible(true)`

Comment: are you using awt or swing ?

Comment: setVisible(true) is a Boolean though right? I dont think I need to be using a Boolean at this part of the assignment. Is there a way to make it visible without using a Boolean?

Comment: If this is `Rectangle` in the AWT library, neither `setVisible(boolean value)` nor `isVisible()` exist. You have to draw it using `java.awt.Graphics`. The `Rectangle` class merely models a rectangle and allows certain operations (e.g. translate).

Answer (score 0):

First off you should tell us what libraries you use. AWT? Swing?

In AWT you should use

singleBrick.setVisible(true);

> `public void setVisible(boolean b)`:
>   Shows or hides this component depending on the value of parameter b.
>   This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy.

```
public boolean isVisible()
```

> Determines whether this component should be visible when its parent is
>   visible. Components are initially visible, with the exception of top
>   level components such as Frame objects.
>       Returns:
>       true if the component is visible, false otherwise

You can think of `isVisible` as a question. Is it visible? The method simply answers the question, true or false. `setVisible` on the other hand is a command: use true if you want to make it visible, false if you want to hide it.